# How can I get different dropdownlist option with the same classes in protractor test?

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, protractor

I've been trying to get a randomly element from my dropdownlist but I have 3 dropdown list with the same class in my page. I tried with the label and following-sibling but it didn't work. 
This question is not about how to get any option in the dropdownlist, but how to get the options of three diferent dropdownlist and click.

First dropdownlist

```
<dropdownlist _ngcontent-xsl-24="">
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
  <!--template bindings={}-->
<option value="null">Selecione uma norma...</option>
<option value="06ea36f0-e6f0-4efe-a1db-8c5b6614f9e0">1356/2016</option>
<option value="7f3fd2de-1a0c-4bf7-a079-bc56a43caca9">126/2016</option>
<option value="5957aaee-1deb-4a9c-8127-b0ac9d208652">127/2016</option>
<option value="f37c484a-1948-44c5-aa42-e29152fdf811">1111/2011</option>
<option value="bdca9e45-c8f1-4c0a-8869-4ac3531a382f">23434/2014</option>
<option value="2ed84235-9dd1-49b0-b3bc-95b69f6a6f84">2334/2013</option>
<option value="57a0321a-ad55-41f3-a720-77546b8a0571">2334/2013</option>
<option value="2fc48229-327a-47c7-9b00-36c8ad5a33b2">2334/2013</option>
<option value="4b1580a2-a618-436c-9471-54b962842b9c">23346/2013</option>
<option value="3572fdf4-f452-4f93-ade8-1e374f6f4e17">35565/2012</option>
<option 
</select>
```

second dropdonwlist

```
<dropdownlist>
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
  <!--template bindings={}-->
<option value="null">Selecione um tipo de cargo...</option>
<option value="3ab69292-eea9-467c-9f25-cef5fd1e9289">Carreira</option>
<option value="69bcde50-8c31-4261-836c-5e06ef5cf373">Comissão</option>
<option value="25af19da-7c39-49a7-8b69-a5dd22e96701">Juiz de Paz</option>
</select>
</dropdownlist>
```

last dropdownlist

```
  <dropdownlist><select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
      <!--template bindings={}--><option value="null">Selecione um nível...</option>
<option value="fc14b561-9899-4d01-aceb-eb7704f38ad3">I</option>
<option value="fd4f8b88-3be7-458c-919b-33aeab8669e1">II</option>
<option value="06361835-be2e-4923-a829-fb5434b197f6">III</option>
<option value="b2ec02c5-b326-4b7c-8f74-36b7956b60b8">IV</option>
<option value="c5460dd4-7e2b-4a4a-a912-578e556d4528">V</option>
<option value="44ef96db-6e6b-479e-a330-e2db3a464bbd">VI</option>
<option value="55231551-2837-4910-a4d7-9053f9d1f79f">VII</option><option value="ed0067a2-506f-48a2-95bc-e5af436f0e80">VIII</option>
    </select>
    </dropdownlist>
```

Comment: I've been trying

var normas = element.all(by.xpath("//label[. = 'Normas']/following-sibling::option")); 

  normas.count().then(function(opcao){
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * opcao);
  }).then(function (escolhaopcao){
   normas.get(escolhaopcao).click();
  });

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get an element randomly in a dropdowlist using protractor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133340/how-can-i-get-an-element-randomly-in-a-dropdowlist-using-protractor)

Comment: It's not because in the other question I have only one dropdownlist, this question is about how to select the dropdowlnlist with same class and same tag.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use element.all() with class name as locator, it will return three dropdown elements
2. Now use each() one result of 1 step, each() will iterate dropdowns one by one from top to bottom
3. Apply chaining on each dropdown element as shown in  code

This way you can get the dropdown you want and select element you want

```
Code Snippet:
var inputOptionText='xyz'

element.all(by.css(".form-control.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng- 
           touched")).each(function(dropdown,index){

            dropdown.element(by.tag("option")).each(function(opt,index){

                         opt.getText().then(function(optionText){

                                     if(optionText==inputText){
                                                   opt.click();
                                                     }
                                   })
               });
        });
```